Google Analytics for WooCommerce
I just use Google Analytics for WooCommerce plugin power by woocomerce it's not working properly
here you can check my plugin setting
: Measurement ID is correct
https://prnt.sc/Vmnc5-vcoN06
Everything is fine but I don't get conversions in my Google Analytics
https://prnt.sc/vsHTqWX3xHp9
Setting view
https://prnt.sc/sBXFZiZdttyq
Please help me to resolve the issue
There is a no any javascript related issue in mysite
